# Validating inexistence of a Max in a continuous function

Tags: calculus, limits

In my assignment I have to prove the following statement:

> Let $f$ be a continuous function which satisfies the following:
>
> For every $x \in \Bbb R $ there is $y>x$ such that $f(y)>f(x)$
>
> Let $a\in \Bbb R$
>
> Prove that for every $M>0$ there is a $y>M$ such that $f(y)>f(a)$

**My solution:**

1. Assume by contradiction that for there is M such that for every $y>M,f(y)\le f(a)$
2. Therefore, f is Bounded because for every $y>M$ there is a value bigger then $f(y)$, which is constant, which is $f(a)$.
3. From the above we can say that f is bounded in $[M,a]$
4. Since f is continuous and blocked in a closed interval, we can say that f has a max value $f(a)$ in the closed interval $[M,a]$
5. Conclusion number 4 is a contradiction to the fact that For every $x \in \Bbb R $ there is $y>x$ such that $f(y)>f(x)$
6. Therefore, for every $M>0$ there is a $y>M$ such that $f(y)>f(a)$

Did I get right here?

Your help is much appreciated.

Alan